# Listening To Azure Queue Messages Win Form

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure

I am running the code below and it is locking up my Win Form. What I am trying to accomplish is displaying a queue message on the form when one comes available.

Here is my code for listening to the queue

```
public void RunListener()
        {
               CloudQueue queue = clnt.GetQueueReference("products");

        while (true)
        {
            CloudQueueMessage qMessage = null;
        do
        {
            qMessage = queue.GetMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            if (qMessage != null)
            {
               //handle message
            }
        }
        while (qMessage != null);


        Thread.Sleep(10000);     
        }
    }
```

How can I use this to get a message then handle it without locking up the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use multi-threading in some fashion, otherwise the code you posted will "lock up" the UI thread until it completes. I would suggest using Async/Await, but a BackgroundWorker or new Thread could be used too.

Also, "Thread.Sleep" is pretty bad to use in this case, since as you have it, it will freeze the UI thread for 10 seconds!

Comment: Can you share an example of how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Look it up, try something, then post another Stack Overflow question with any new problems you encounter.